# Type-theory, is predicate for Abstraction judgment unnecessary

Tags: type-theory

In [Benjamin Pierce's book, Types and Programming languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) I am curious why we need a condition that $x: T_1$. I'm having a hard time coming up with an example that type checks but the program does not actually evaluate (progress) and vice versa (preservation). I'm arguing if we remove x$: T_1$ then the body of lambda function in order to evaluate should give us  $x: T_1$.

Thanks for any help or hint.

[image]

Comment: Knowing nothing about the book's approach, but something about typed lambda calculus, this sounds like an odd question. In the treatments I've seen of $\lambda_\to$, the $x:T$ isn't a "condition", it's part of the syntax of the language; a language in which terms aren't type-checked later, but only ever occur with a specific type attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The progress and preservation theorems combine to tell us that, provided our code is well typed, its execution is safe. In its simplest form, this means that well typed code will always execute without crashing, though it might loop.

More specifically, the progress theorem tells us that, given a well typed expression 
$x : \tau$, we know that either $x$ is a value, or $x$ can step to some $x'$. That is, execution of $x$ can always *progress* if $x$ is not yet a value.

The preservation theorem tells us that, if $x : \tau$ and $x$ steps to $x'$, then $x' : \tau$ too. That is, being well typed is *preserved* when we step.

Using these two theorems, it is an easy induction to show that well typed code cannot crash. We start with $x:\tau$ well typed, but this steps to $x'$ by progress. Then by preservation $x' : \tau$. Then by progress $x'$ steps to $x''$. But by preservation $x'' : \tau$ too, and so on. Either we eventually reach a value, in which case we are done, or we loop infinitely.

---

You mention you are having a hard time coming up with a program which is well typed, but which does not evaluate. The reason you are having a hard time is because the above theorem says it is not possible!

To make this more obvious, consider an extension of the simply typed lambda calculus with a type of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ subject to the following rules:

[image: typing and dynamics for N]

Now we can consider the program $(\lambda x. x) + [2]$ - notice this is not well typed. Now $(\lambda x . x) + [2]$ is *not* a value, but there are no rules in the dynamics saying where it should step to! Thus our program has "crashed" - it isn't a value, but it cannot step.

If we instead consider the program $(\lambda x. x)([3] + [2])$, it is clear that the following evaluation works:

$$(\lambda x . x)([3] + [2]) \mapsto (\lambda x . x)([5]) \mapsto [5]$$

Since $[5]$ is a value, we are done.

---

Notice the importance of typing here - types are how we gain control over program execution, because types tell us that our programs are of a certain pre-determined form. Indeed, the way we *prove* progress is by inducting on types!

As an example, part of a progress proof might be:

Say $e : \tau$ and $e \mapsto e'$. If $\tau = \mathbb{N}$

By an inversion lemma, it suffices to check the two cases 
$e = [n]$ and $e = e_1 + e_2$ (where $e_1 : \mathbb{N}$ and $e_2 : \mathbb{N}$)

If $e = [n]$, then $e \text{ val}$ and we are done.

If $e = e_1 + e_2$, then $e_1, e_2 : \mathbb{N}$, so by induction $e_1$ and $e_2$ are either values, or can evaluate further.

If $e_1$ and $e_2$ are both values, then (by another inversion lemma), they are of the form $e_1 = [m]$ and $e_2 = [n]$. Then $e = [m] + [n]$ and can step to $[m+n]$.

If $e_1$ is a value, but $e_2$ isn't, then $e_2 \mapsto e_2'$ and so we see
$e = e_1 + e_2$ can step to $e_1 + e_2'$.

Finally, if $e_1$ isn't a value, then $e_1 \mapsto e_1'$ and we see
$e = e_1 + e_2$ can step to $e_1' + e_2$.

---

The reason this induction goes through is because of the typing judgement! It would be impossible to prove this theorem without the assumption that $x$ is well typed - that is, without the assumption that $x : \tau$ is derivable for some $\tau$.

I'm not sure what you mean by "if we remove $x:T_1$, then the body of the lambda function in order to evaluate should give us $x:T_1$". One thing you might be referring to is "type inference", which allows the programmer to not specify certain types because the compiler can infer what these types should be. You are right in assuming that, by looking at the body of the lambda, a compiler might be able to figure out what the "correct" type of $x$ should be in order to make the body typecheck. But this procedure can be complicated, even undecidable in many cases, and the existence of such a program changes nothing about our assumptions for progress and preservation. Just because we as programmers are not writing down the types doesn't mean the types aren't there.

If I've misunderstood something in your question, feel free to let me know. I'll happily update my answer.

---

I hope this helps ^_^